# angularjs - Set time using range slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use ionic range to set a period of time with a step of 15minutes.
Ionic range works just like a common range input with min,max, step, value.

Here's the range html code:

```
<div class="item range">
  <input type="range" min="0.15" max="12" value="0" step="0.15" ng-model="TimeValue" ng-change="setTime(TimeValue)">
</div>
```

And here's the function that i'm calling on change:

```
$scope.setTime = (value) ->
   $scope.hours = Math.floor(value / 0.6);
   $scope.minutes = value - ($scope.hours * 0.6);
```

Unfortunately, this is not working.

What I'm trying to achieve is a slider with a step of 0.15(minutes) that automatically creates an hour when it gets to 0.6 and than it starts again at 1.15(hours) and so on.

I'm following this answer here: [using ionic range to set months and years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750226/using-ionic-range-to-set-months-and-years) but that's for years and months and the calculation is different.

Here's a quick demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZVPRv?editors=1010

**EDIT**

New demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZVPRv?editors=1010

Comment: I can see it sets hour and mins, so what is not working ?

Comment: If you slide, it sets hours and minutes, but the values (specially minutes) is wrong. It is right the first step (up until 1 hours) but then it goes to 0.15000000002 - 0.30000000004 - 0.45000000007 and so on, increasing continuously. This may lead to delays and I need this to be really precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code buddy, hope this what you needed-

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){    
  $scope.setTime = function (value) {
    $scope.hours = Math.floor(value / 0.6);
  if(($scope.TimeValue % 0.6) == 0 ){
    $scope.minutes = 0;
    }else{
      if($scope.TimeValue <= .6){
        $scope.minutes = Math.round((value - ($scope.hours))*100);  
      }else{
        value = Math.round((value - ($scope.hours * .6))*100);
        $scope.minutes = value;
      }
    }
  }
  $scope.TimeValue = 0.15;
}])
```

There were calculation issue, check it here-
http://codepen.io/himanshuapril1/pen/eZVPXe?editors=1010

Comment: that is almost perfect, but there's still some issues with the "default value", can you please check that as well? than i select your answer :)
thanks man

Comment: here you can see why i still have a problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZxgVY
basically, I need a format that allows me to add values back to the slider as well, but keeping it as minutes and hours properly

Comment: Check this one, got everything u need - http://codepen.io/himanshuapril1/pen/eZVXmV

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't work on my app. I have the slider inside a popup, should it affect the behave?

Comment: and here's what happens on my app: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNQavV?editors=1010. Same here. I'm using the slider inside a popup and here you can see the same issue i've got

Comment: It is creating infinite popups in DOM on click on `open modal` button, I think there is some other issue, the click event is getting fired infinite times, check with `inspect element`. Let me try what's the main issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109007/discussion-between-nick-and-himanshu-aggarwal).